# Square root function in F#

Tags: f#

How can we find the square root of a number in F#? Do we have a Sqrt function in F# just like we have Math.Sqrt() function in Java? I am a beginner in F# and couldn't find any significant help on the internet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

F# already has a [`sqrt`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#sqrt) function defined, so you should just be able to use:

```
sqrt x
```

where `x` is the value you wish to find the root of.

Comment: But typing in sqrt x was not giving me the answer. Indeed I was getting an error. Then I tried Math. Sqrt (x) and it worked. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2549169: It would depend on where you were trying to use it, I suspect. It should work fine in the right context.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, F# comes with a "sqrt" function.  Called "sqrt" :)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2008/09/01/the-f-operators-and-basic-functions.aspx

Many more numerical libraries are available for F#, either open source (e.g. CodePlex) or from 3rd party vendors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh304372%28v=vs.100%29.aspx